# How to prevent bootstrap css class to override my custom css class

Tags: jquery, css, class, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have some textboxes in my form that have the bootstrap `form-control` class.

```
media="screen"
.form-control {
    ...
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, this class defines the border of those textboxes. When the content of one of the textboxes is invalid, with jQuery I add a custom class named `form-error` that changes the border of this textbox.

```
.form-error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

However, my class is overrided by the `form-control` class. I don't know why but it might be because of a media query (the developer tools are showing `media="screen"` above the `form-control` class).

How can I get my `form-error` class to override the `form-control` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an issue of specificity, you could be more specific and use something like this:

```
form .form-group .form-error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/26Hs5/)

Remember, stylesheets are cascade. This means they are read from top to bottom. You should place the styling for `.form-error` below `.form-control` in order to prevent it form being overwritten.

Comment: being more specific by adding form before my class name did the trick! but I tested to import my custom css after bootstrap.min and it did the trick too! 2 solutions for 1 question, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Also another option is to add "!important" to the style. Please check.

eg. .

```
form-error {
    border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: I prefer to just organize the order of my imports